# Cannot enter text in input field in IE6?

Tags: internet-explorer-6, input

Please let me know how do I enable to enter text in input field in IE6 ?

Comment: Could you be more precise? HTML? CSS? JS? ASP.NET? PHP? ROR? SRS BSNS?

Comment: can you post the sample code of your form?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the [`readonly`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-readonly) and/or [`disabled`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-disabled) attributes.

```
document.getElementById('yourInputId').readonly = '';
document.getElementById('yourInputId').disabled = '';
```

or:

```
document.getElementById('yourInputId').removeAttribute('readonly');
```

Answer (score 0):

with jquery

```
$('#id').attr("disabled", false); 

$('#id').removeAttr("readonly");
```

if it is what you mean ?